# Adding a list of forces to a particle in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, particles, particle-system

I'm kinda new to c++, so sorry if it's a dumb question.

I have a struct that represents a particle in a particle system. Along with the standard stuff like position, velocity, and mass, I want to give it a list of forces, such that each force is a function, where I pass it the particle, and based on the current state of the particle (or not), this function returns a force vector. Ideally I would sum up the results of every such force vector to get a net force, which I could then use to calculate the velocity of the particle for the next tick.

This is what I want my particle to look like

```
struct particle {
    double mass;

    // position
    double x, y, z;

    // velocity
    double dx, dy, dz;


    std::list<function> forces;
};
```

Now my question is: Can I do this without implementing a generic force base class that implements a function to calculate a force? Is there a way I can just specify a list of functions with the same call signature?

Comment: From a performance point of view, you most certainly want `std::vector` instead of `std::list`.

Comment: Any reason why? If I just iterate over the forces sequentially at each tick, would it make a difference?

Comment: The iterations over vector is a bit faster, since its elements occupy a contiguous area in memory, and since you don't need to read a pointer and follow it.

Comment: @chrisnakovski Iterating a vector is not just a little bit faster, it is a lot faster. Every single jump in the list is a cash miss (usually). The vector works nicely with the prefetcher.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: You should add the `c++11` tag, as c++98 doesn't have `std::function` .

Comment: @BaummitAugen in his case, jumps are unlikely, for pretty obvious reasons.

Comment: But it can be done without c++11 using function pointers.  Are you using c++11 or would a function pointer based answer be helpful?

Comment: @user31264 Jumps of length 1 (e.g. 1st to 2nd element) count too in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee that all functions will have the same method signature, then you can use the templated [function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)[cppreference.com] class.  I've modified your sample to illustrate how to use it.

```
#include <functional>
#include <list>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

struct particle 
{
    double mass;

    // position
    double x, y, z;

    // velocity
    double dx, dy, dz;

    // A list of forces that take a particle and return a double
    // The space between the two > symbols is needed in pre-c++11 compilers.
    list<function<double(const particle&)> > forces;
};

// An example function to calculate the force due to gravity.
double gravity(const particle& p)
{
    return p.mass * -9.8;
}

// Making something up for air resistance
double resistance(const particle& p)
{
    return 0.1 * sqrt(p.dx * p.dx + p.dy * p.dy + p.dz * p.dz);
}

int main()
{
    particle p;
    p.mass = 10;
    p.x = 0;
    p.y = 100;
    p.z = 0;

    p.dx = 0;
    p.dy = 0;
    p.dz = 0;
    p.forces.push_back(gravity);
    p.forces.push_back(resistance);
}
```

If you're going to be dealing with three dimensional forces, you'll probably want more information in the return type than just a double, but this should be a good starting point.  Also, if you have a c++11 compatible compiler, you may also want to lookup [lambda functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) so that the functions can be created in the same line.

Comment: Thanks to @user31264.  The function class doesn't exist before c++11, but [function pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) could be used instead.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::function. Something like this:

```
// define a type for the function
typedef std::function< void(particle const&, float *fxfyfz) > forcer_function;
std::vector< forcer_function > forces;
```

Now, some words with regards to performance. Since this is particles you're talking about, I'm assuming that you have a reasonably large number of particles (eg some hundreds at least). So I'm assuming that you have an interest in getting this code to run moderately fast.

So, first, using std::list for your container is not advised due to bad cache properties. It will make your code *much* slower. Therefore, the use of std::vector.

Second, adding the list of forces as a member of your particle structure is uncommon. Do you really want to use different forces per particle? Typically, there are <5 forces and >100-1000 particles. If you can use the same collection of forces for all of your particles, then moving the forces out of your particle class will give you a gain. For example,

```
struct particle
{
    double mass;
    // position
    double x, y, z;
    // velocity
    double dx, dy, dz;
};
struct particle_container
{
    std::vector< particle > particles;
    std::vector< forcer_function > forces;

    void update();
};

void particle_container::update()
{
    for(particle &p : particles) {
        double rx, ry, rz;
        rx = ry = rz = 0.0;
        for(forcer_function fn : forces) {
            double f[3];
            fn(p, &f[0]);
            rx += f[0];
            ry += f[1];
            rz += f[2];
        }
        // integrate resulting force, etc
        // ...
    }
}
```

If OTOH you really want to use per-particle forces, you can still use the approach I outlined above by grouping particles with the same force collection in different container objects. Then you can reuse all of the above, and adding one more class will fix it:

```
struct particle_groups
{
    std::vector< particle_container > groups;
    void update();
};
void particle_groups::update()
{
    for(auto &g : groups) {
        g.update();
    }
};
```

If you really, really, want no grouping, then at least consider whether there's a way you can use particle members zeroing out inactive forces.  Then you could still use the approach above. For example, like this:

```
struct particle
{
    double mass;
    // position
    double x, y, z;
    // velocity
    double dx, dy, dz;

    // is gravity active? either 1.0 or 0.0
    double grav;
    // is player interaction active? either 1.0 or 0.0
    double player;
    // etc... for all possible forces
};
```

Then just multiply eg, your resulting gravity by the particle's grav member, and you effectively switch gravity off or on for that particle, according to whether particle.grav's value is 1.0 or 0.0.

Finally, std::function is slow. You can use a mix of the two approaches above and use a single function. Like this:

```
struct particle
{
    double mass;
    // position
    double x, y, z;
    // velocity
    double dx, dy, dz;
};
struct force_settings
{
    double grav;
    double attractor;
    double player;
    //etc...
};
struct particle_container
{
    // no need to keep pointers to functions
    force_settings forces;
    std::vector< particle > particles;

    void update();
    void compute_forces(particle const& p, double *rf) const
    {
        // zero resulting force
        rf[0] = rf[1] = rf[2] = 0.0;
        // compute gravity, (assume y axis)
        rf[1] += forces.grav * 9.8; // will be either 9.8 or 0.0
        // compute attractor
        double ax = p.x - attractor.x;
        double ay = p.y - attractor.y;
        double az = p.z - attractor.z;
        rf[0] += forces.attraction * ax*ax;
        rf[1] += forces.attraction * ay*ay;
        rf[2] += forces.attraction * az*az;
        // etc... more forces here
   }
};

void particle_container::update()
{
    for(particle &p : particles) {
        double rf[3];
        compute_forces(p, &rf);
        // integrate, etc...
    }
}
```